# GSAP DrawSVGPlugin in Ionic

Tags: typescript, svg, ionic-framework, gsap

I want to implement this plugin in Ionic3 . As I know a npm package doesn't have plugins from club, nor @types/gsap. I added DrawSVGPlugin.js into node_modules/gsap and later recreated an android platform.
In .ts file as import I tried:

```
import { DrawSVGPlugin } from "gsap/DrawSVGPlugin";
```

and as calling plugin:

```
TweenLite.to("#svg_1", 1, {drawSVG:"40% 60%", ease:Power1.easeInOut});
```

my html source of svg:

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <line stroke-linecap="undefined" stroke-linejoin="undefined" id="svg_1" y2="45.78805" x2="87.36405" y1="45.24458" x1="8.28813" stroke-width="12.5" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Or is there different way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using DrawSVG in Ionic (I've replicated and tested this method on several projects):

1. Place the GSAP file you will be using under `src/assets/javascripts`, and call the script file as you would in an HTML inside your `index.html`:

   ```
   <script src="assets/javascripts/gsap/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/javascripts/gsap/plugins/DrawSVGPlugin.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Add the GSAP variables you will be using

   ```
   /*
     Normal imports here..
   */
   import { LoginPage } from "../login/login";

   declare var TimelineLite: any;        
   declare var TweenLite: any;
   declare var Power1: any;

   @Component({
     selector: 'page-profile',
     templateUrl: 'profile.html',
     providers: [Data, Api, DatePipe]
   })

   export class ProfilePage {
   ...
   ```
3. Use like normal. As you already know, SVGs must be inlined.

   ```
   TweenLite.to("#svg_1", 1, {drawSVG:"40% 60%", ease:Power1.easeInOut});
   ```

Comment: I did as you suggested, but I have that error: Argument of type '{ drawSVG: string; ease: Quad; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TweenConfig'. 
            Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'drawSVG' does not exist in type 'TweenConfig'. 
      L15:  test() {
      L16:    TweenMax.to("#svg_1", 1, {drawSVG:"40% 60%", ease:Power1.easeInOut});

Should I somehow declare that drawSVG? I do not see any declaration of it in your code.

Comment: I just tested it in an app inside the Xcode Simulator and it worked fine as in  the example. Could you try using the TweenMax file instead of TweenLite, and removing the GSAP/DrawSVG typings?

Comment: I changed it to TweenLite and it started to work (even with npm gsap and @types).

Comment: Great to know! Edited the answer to reflect that.